# Dataweave scripting issue

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I need to add "\" to my string in dataweave but it is not getting \ character

```
%dw 2.0 output application/json --- {  "pdEndDate":  "\/Date(" ++ vars.date.startDate ++ ")\/"   }
```

Actual:

```
{
  "pdEndDate": " /Date(1562895466000)N/"
}
```

Expected

```
{
  "pdEndDate": "\/Date(1562895466000)\/"
}
```

Comment: You should not need to escape a character for JSON. DataWeave should do that automatically. Are you having any issues with the forward slashes?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `\` with another `\`.

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 
--- 
{  "pdEndDate":  "\\/Date(" ++ vars.date.startDate ++ ")\\/"   }
```

But your output in JSON will be the following (with `\\`).

```
{
  "pdEndDate": "\\/Date(1562895466000)\\/"
}
```

Since in JSON `\` is the escape char for strings, so you can't have just one, you need to escape it to include it in a string.